# How do I program a serial sniff that does not redirect data to a different serial port

Tags: raspberry-pi, monitoring, serial-port

I need to make a monitoring application for a friend of mine. The thing I need to monitor is a hardware device's program on a Raspberry Pi. However, the program I need to monitor is hardwired to **only** read data from `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

How do I sniff data that is going through that specific serial port without changing what serial port the data is coming through with.

I tried strace, but for my needs it will not work.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point, do you want to multiplex /dev/ttyUSB0 so you can access data on this tty while an other program is using it?

Comment: correct, However my application will ONLY read from the serial connection. It will never try to write anything to it. The hardware device will be the only thing the will read and write on it.

Comment: It's been a while since I did not used it so I have to read the man to post a concrete solution, but socat seems to be the tool you are looking for.